# Windows 7 not recognizing second lan card?

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

I just got a second LAN card, because I want to share my internet connection with my laptop. I put the LAN card in the computer, but it doesn't recognize it. I tried Everest, but it still does not recognize it. Does anyone have a suggestion why is this happening? I'm using Win7.

Comment: if you could state *at least* the card's make and model, it would **quite** help answerers here.

Comment: Why didn't you get a hub or a router? In that way you didn't have the extra burden of getting the hardware device to work and you don't need the computer when you are using the laptop and could even go wireless when you want to.